# Linking two cell values together in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

Hi thank you for helping,

I am looking for a way to link 2 cells together in Google Sheets, where the output of either one will depend on the input of the other.

Let me give an example
I have a database of column with codes and next to it corresponding names, simple example below.

```
DATABASE 1
     CODE | NAME
     -----------
       146  |  Aba
       234  |  Bac
       365  |  Cge
```

When filling out an order I want to be able to either put in the code and the sheet will automatically lookup the name and fill it, or put in the name and the sheet will automatically fill in the code.

example:

```
Order 1
my input                       finished
     CODE | NAME                 CODE | NAME
     -----------  -> PROCESS ->  -----------
     146  |                      146  |  Aba 
          |  Cge                 365  |  Cge
```

I am looking to figure out what the "process" could be to get the the desired solution. I am not good at coding myself and don't really know where I could begin, but I was thinking that one solution could be using the VLOOKUP function to go down each row, check if there is a value in the CODE column, then VLOOOKUP the corresponding NAME value from database, if no CODE value, then see if there is a NAME value and VLOOKUP the CODE value. Then move to the next row.

Thank you for taking your time to read this I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Converting column letters to numbers or numbers to letters

You can perform what you describe with these functions.  I have ascii to character and column letter to column numbers examples.  Copy all of these functions into Code.gs and then you have to go to a blank page and rename it to 'Contacts' and then run the setupOnEdit() function.  I chose to use columns A and B.  The way it's setup now if you type spreadsheet columns in letters then column numbers will appear in the adjacent column.  Or if you type in columns numbers then the letters will appear in the other column.  I think you just wanted each column to go one way.  And that's possible to.  I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```
function getASCIIObject(){
  var aObj={};
  for(var i=32;i<127;i++){
    var s=Utilities.formatString('%s',String.fromCharCode(i));
    if(s!='='){
      aObj[i]=s;
      aObj[s]=i;
    }
  }
  return aObj;
}

function getColumnsObject(){
  var cObj={};
  var chA=[];
  var colA=[];
  for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){chA.push(String.fromCharCode(i));}
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<26;j++){
      if(i==0){
        colA.push(chA[j]);
      }
      if(i>0){
        colA.push(chA[i-1] + chA[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<colA.length;i++){
    cObj[i+1]=colA[i];
    cObj[colA[i]]=i+1;
  }
  return cObj;
}


function dCode(key,mode){
  if(key){
    var mode=mode || 'ASCII';
    if(mode=='ASCII'){
      var dObj=getASCIIObject();
      return dObj[key];
    }
    if(mode=='COLUMNS'){
      var dObj=getColumnsObject();
      return dObj[isNaN(key)?key.toUpperCase():key];
    }  
    if(mode=='DICT'){
      var dObj=getMyDictionary();
      return dObj[key];
    } 
  }
  throw('Error; Invalid params in dCode()');
}

function setupEditTrigger(funcName) {  
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().indexOf(funcName)==-1){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).forSpreadsheet(getGlobal('SSId')).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function setupOnEdit(){
  setupEditTrigger('decodeColumns');
}

function decodeColumns(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var value=rg.getValue();
  Logger.log('rg: %s sh: %s col: %s row: %s value: %s',rg.getA1Notation(),sh.getName(),col,row,value);
  if(sh.getName()=='Contacts' && col==1){
    rg.offset(0,+1).setValue(dCode(value,'DICT'));
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Contacts' && col==2){
    rg.offset(0,-1).setValue(dCode(value,'DICT'));
  }
}

function getMyDictionary(sheetname,keycolumn){
  var sheetname=sheetname ||'Dictionary';
  var keycolumn=keycolumn || 1;
  var valuecolumn=keycolumn + 1;
  var dObj={};
  if(sheetname && keycolumn){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,keycolumn,sh.getLastRow(),2);
    var codeA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<codeA.length;i++){
      if(codeA[i][0]){
        dObj[codeA[i][0]]=codeA[i][1];
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
    return dObj;
  }else{
    throw('Error: Invalid params in getMyDictionary()');
  }
}
```

Here's a second version that gives you two dictionary tabs to work with.  One is Dictionary and the other is Dictionary2.  But of course you can change them to whatever you wish.

```
function getASCIIObject(){
  var aObj={};
  for(var i=32;i<127;i++){
    var s=Utilities.formatString('%s',String.fromCharCode(i));
    if(s!='='){
      aObj[i]=s;
      aObj[s]=i;
    }
  }
  return aObj;
}

function getColumnsObject(){
  var cObj={};
  var chA=[];
  var colA=[];
  for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){chA.push(String.fromCharCode(i));}
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<26;j++){
      if(i==0){
        colA.push(chA[j]);
      }
      if(i>0){
        colA.push(chA[i-1] + chA[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<colA.length;i++){
    cObj[i+1]=colA[i];
    cObj[colA[i]]=i+1;
  }
  return cObj;
}


function dCode(key,mode){
  if(key){
    var mode=mode || 'ASCII';
    if(mode=='ASCII'){
      var dObj=getASCIIObject();
      if(dObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return dObj[key];
      }
    }
    if(mode=='COLUMNS'){
      var dObj=getColumnsObject();
      key=isNaN(key)?key.toUpperCase():key;
      if(dObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return dObj[key];
      }
    }  
    if(mode=='DICT1'){
      var dObj=getMyDictionary();
      if(dObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return dObj[key];
      }
    } 
    if(mode=='DICT2'){
      var dObj=getMyDictionary('Dictionary2');
      if(dObj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return dObj[key];
      }   
    } 
  }else{
    throw('Error; Invalid params in dCode()');
  }
  return nill;
}

function setupEditTrigger(funcName) {  
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().indexOf(funcName)==-1){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).forSpreadsheet(getGlobal('SSId')).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function setupOnEdit(){
  setupEditTrigger('decodeColumns');
}

function decodeColumns(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var value=rg.getValue();
  Logger.log('rg: %s sh: %s col: %s row: %s value: %s',rg.getA1Notation(),sh.getName(),col,row,value);
  if(sh.getName()=='Contacts' && col==1){
    rg.offset(0,+1).setValue(dCode(value,'DICT1'));
  }
  if(sh.getName()=='Contacts' && col==2){
    rg.offset(0,-1).setValue(dCode(value,'DICT2'));
  }
}

function getMyDictionary(sheetname,keycolumn){
  var sheetname=sheetname ||'Dictionary';
  var keycolumn=keycolumn || 1;
  var valuecolumn=keycolumn + 1;
  var dObj={};
  if(sheetname && keycolumn){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,keycolumn,sh.getLastRow(),2);
    var codeA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<codeA.length;i++){
      if(codeA[i][0]){
        dObj[codeA[i][0]]=codeA[i][1];
      }else{
        break;
      }
    }
    return dObj;
  }else{
    throw('Error: Invalid params in getMyDictionary()');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, however the codes/names aren't just the column numbers

Comment: They can be anything you want him to be. What would you like them to be?

Comment: It’s basically a dictionary. It’s constructed with object properties and in this case I have key value pairs and value Key pairs so that the conversion is bidirectional.

Comment: I modified the answer and now it's setup to build the dictionary object from the first two columns of a sheet(tab) named Dictionary.  You put the key in column one and the value in column 2.  They can be whatever you wish.

Comment: I've added a second version that gives you two dictionaries so that you can use a different one for each column that you change.  You can enter whatever you wish.